# Second and Third entries of nth-child in CSS are not being recognised

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get ":nth-child" class to work with a html table.

I would like different columns to have different text alignments and padding.

I have created a new entry for each child in the CSS with their unique settings but only the first entry works. The remainder seem to completely ignored.

I thought maybe I couldn't adjust more than one child under each other in the CSS the way I have laid it out but have found nothing to say I can't. I feel it may be something to with the way the child is being counted from the parent and that my first entry for the child can be the only one. After that its becoming a child of a child, if that makes sense?

Am I on the right track here or just doing something completely wrong through bad understanding of how it is meant to work?

Any help or a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have worked up...

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
  width: 70%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
table td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
​ table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
​ table td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
​
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
    <td>seven</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>eight</td>
    <td>nine</td>
    <td>ten</td>
    <td>eleven</td>
    <td>twelve</td>
    <td>thirteen</td>
    <td>fourteen</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift replies! All I can say is wow... I don't know how I missed that and feel a little silly now, I must have copied it from somewhere and it just carried across.

I deleted the entries in my CSS and retyped the two offending ones and all works well now so thanks for the help! It was starting to drive me a little nuts as I couldn't see the blank space or strange character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 table td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
​ table td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

These are not used, because there is a strange character infront of table. Remove the spaces and they work. See http://jsfiddle.net/sfpq4hrL/3/

This http://jsfiddle.net/o618ngfz/ is your code (invalid) in jsfiddle. You will notice the invalid char.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1t4ns2ea/)

There was problem copying your code into the fiddle because in front of:

```
 table td:nth-child(2) {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 10px;
}
 table td:nth-child(3) {
      text-align: right;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 15px;
}
```

you have a blank space. Remove the blank space and it will work.